# Program to compress a string

Tags: java, string

I'm writing a program that compresses strings using run-length encoding.

E.g. for input "aaabbccccddd", output should be "a3b2c4d3".

Currently the program shows no output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String words1 = "aabbbcccc";
    String words2 = compress(words1);
    System.out.println(words2);
  }

private static String compress(String w1) {
    StringBuilder w2 = new StringBuilder();
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < w1.length(); ) {
        k++;
        if(i+1>w1.length() || w1.charAt(i) != w1.charAt(i+1)) {
          w2.append(w1.charAt(i));
          w2.append(k);
          k = 0;
        }
    }
    return ((w2.length() > w1.length())? w1: w2.toString());
}
```

Output shows nothing in IntelliJ and I can't figure out why!! Also tried without `StringBuilder`. Even tried without `StringBuilder` and changing the return type to `void` in case it was a problem with handling a `String`. Same, no result.

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger of your IDE. You can view the inner workings of the program and find out where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eran said, you forgot the `i++` part. Also, `i+1>w1.length()` should be `i+1>=w1.length()`. It should work with those two changes.

```
private static String compress(String w1) {
    StringBuilder w2 = new StringBuilder();
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < w1.length(); i++) {
        k++;
        if(i+1>=w1.length() || w1.charAt(i) != w1.charAt(i+1)) {
          w2.append(w1.charAt(i));
          w2.append(k);
          k = 0;
        }
    }
    return ((w2.length() > w1.length())? w1: w2.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I missed out the incrementation and caused the crazy mess I was in!!!

Answer (score 3):

One thing you forgot is `i++` in your for loop. This causes an infinite loop.

Besides that, you have an issue with the condition of your loop. It should be `i<w1.length()-1` to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException` caused by `w1.charAt(i+1)`.

Once you change that, you'll see that the last character of the `String` is not handled. You can handle it outside the loop.

```
private static String compress(String w1) {
  StringBuilder w2 = new StringBuilder();
  int k =0;
  for (int i=0; i < w1.length()-1; i++) {
    k++;
    if (w1.charAt(i) != w1.charAt(i+1)) {
      w2.append(w1.charAt(i));
      w2.append(k);
      k=0;
    }
  }

  w2.append (w1.charAt (w1.length ()-1));
  w2.append (k+1);

  return ((w2.length() > w1.length())? w1: w2.toString());
}
```

This outputs

```
a3b2c4d3
```

for the input

```
aaabbccccddd
```

EDIT:

As David commented correctly, you do have code to handle the last character within the loop. You just had a wrong range check in the `if` statement.

The following fixes all the issues, without the need to handle the last character separately:

```
private static String compress(String w1) {
  StringBuilder w2 = new StringBuilder();
  int k =0;
  for (int i=0; i < w1.length(); i++) {
    k++;
    if (i+1 >= w1.length() || w1.charAt(i) != w1.charAt(i+1)) {
      w2.append(w1.charAt(i));
      w2.append(k);
      k=0;
    }
  }

  return ((w2.length() > w1.length())? w1: w2.toString());
}
```

Comment: I don't think you fully understand OP's code. The last character was supposed to be handled inside the loop by the `i+1>w1.length()` part (which you've forgotten to delete as it's not needed in your solution). The problem is that it should be `i+1>=w1.length()`. This should prevent the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.